# Why does the `System.String.GetHasCode` return different values once I rerun my app?

Tags: .net, string, hash, clr, implementation

Why does the `System.String.GetHasCode` return different values once I rerun my app?

E.g. I have the app:

```
using System;

namespace myprogram
{
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
           Console.WriteLine("foo".GetHashCode());
        }
    }
}
```

I run the app twice and get the different outputs:

```
user@user MINGW64 /c/Projects/dotNet/Console.NET
$ dotnet run
1430600909

user@user MINGW64 /c/Projects/dotNet/Console.NET
$ dotnet run
208120252
```

Does that mean that the `System.String.GetHasCode` is implemented incorrectly in the .NET Core? Because according to the quote from the **CLR via C#** we have the following convention:

> Objects with the same value should return the same code. For example, two String objects
>   with the same text should return the same hash code value.

There is nothing about the app being run only once in the quote. I.e. I understand the quote with application to my case as follows: if the values of the two strings are equal, then the hash codes should be equal even after the app rerun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `GetHashCode` can be implementation dependent and is not guaranteed to be identical across multiple versions or platforms. For security purposes the .NET Core implementation uses a feature called "randomized string hashing" which creates different hash values for each application run.

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.gethashcode?view=netcore-3.0) (emphasis by me):

> The hash code itself is not guaranteed to be stable. Hash codes for identical strings can differ across .NET implementations, across .NET versions, and across .NET platforms (such as 32-bit and 64-bit) for a single version of .NET. In some cases, they can even differ by application domain. **This implies that two subsequent runs of the same program may return different hash codes.**

The result is still stable within the same application run, in this example you will see three equal numbers printed:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("foo".GetHashCode());
        Console.WriteLine("foo".GetHashCode());
        Console.WriteLine("foo".GetHashCode());
    }
}
```